# How can I search in Visual Studio Code/IDE for a specific term which does not include another term?

Tags: html, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

I would like to know if it's possible to search in my code for a term ("<img") which in the same line of code it does not contain another term ("alt=").

In other words, I would like to know if it's possible to search for all image tags that does not have the alt attribute in it and how to do it.

For example, I need to find these:

```
<img src="some-image.png" />
```

But in this search I need to ignore those which already have the attribute:

```
<img src="another-image.png" alt="Some text" />
```

Is this possible on Visual Studio Code? If not, is it possible on the Visual Studio (IDE)?

Comment: Sounds like the perfect use case for the regex search feature

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the VS Code search box (ctrl + f), or in the search sidebar, there are 3 icons in the search text box. The first is Match Case, second is Match Whole Word, and the third is Use Regular Expression. That is the one you want to select. After selecting that, paste this regex into the search text box.

```
^(?!.*?alt=).*img\ssrc.*
```

You can search the document using Ctrl + f or search everywhere with the sidebar search tool and it will only match image tags without the alt attribute.

Answer (score 2):

I saw there is a right answer but it took me a long time to figure the right regex for this :) so I thought it might help someone.

you have to press `CTRL + F5` , then choose the use regular expression option, then paste

`^(?!.*\b(alt)\b)(?=.*\b(img)\b).*$`

the first group rejects the word alt wherever it appears and the second group searches for the word img.

hope this could help!

Comment: Why would you want to reject the word alt? In this OP's case, it's clear they're trying to make the site accessible. Thus, finding `alt=""` (empty alt attributes) would also be valid in the results. Can you update this to include the occurrence of empty alt attributes as well?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex for a couple more test cases: (1) `img` tag has an `alt` attribute before the `src` attribute - shouldn't be found I assume and (2) two or more `img` tags on the same line.  These cases may or not be of concern.

Find:  `(<img\s)(?![^>]*alt=)([^>]*>)`

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/TWMa40/1)